# How can I add tables to a model?

Tags: entity-framework

I added new table to my database and I managed to add it to my data model, using "Update model from database" option. But I cant generate class to acces this table in code. "Add code generation item" results into creating classes for all tables i have in my database.

Well, it seems to be a duplicate, but don't delete this topic at once please, for I've been searching for solution quite a long time and found nothing helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add code generation item again if you already did it once. Normally it should be enough to save your EDMX file and generation should trigger. If it for any reason doesn't work, right click on `.tt` file responsible for generating your classes in the *Solution Explorer* and select *Run Custom Tool* from the context menu.